# The ID of Button in Fragment issue

Tags: java, android

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @BindView(R.id.button_show_toast)
    Button button_show_toast;
    Unbinder unbinder;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        button_show_toast.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        // Why v.getId() isn't equal to R.id.button_show_toast?
        Log.d("v.getId()", i + "");
        Log.d("R.id.button_show_toast", R.id.button_show_toast + "");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "I am come from fragment.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I want to use a switch function to manage the button clicked event. However, the `v.getId()` isn't equal to `R.id.button_show_toast` and I can't find out the answer right now.

The `log` show me the `v.getId()` isn't equal to `R.id.button_show_toast`. Hope some one can help me.

**Here are the Log information:**

> D/v.getId(): 2131492957
>
> D/R.id.button_show_toast: 2131492992

Also, I posted the `fragment_a.xml` file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_show_toast"
    style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

Comment: could you show us the fragment xml? may be some view is overlapping your button?

Comment: Possibly your project is having two or more view having id `button_show_toast`. Try to search.

Comment: There is only one id button_show_toast.

Comment: BTW, the Toast can show. Hmm...I will create another project to find out this issue tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in onCreateView()

```
button_show_toast=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_show_toast); // add this line
```

whole code :

```
Button button_show_toast;

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
                unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
button_show_toast=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_show_toast); // add this line
                return view;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I used the ButterKnife to bind the view with my fragment. So is my usage on ButterKnife wrong? Please advise. Thanks again.

Comment: may be in your project buttons have same id "button_show_toast" datsy it give error. just search your project this id is using some where or not. otherwise there is not issue to use ButterKnife.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
@OnClick(R.id.button_show_toast) 
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    // Why v.getId() isn't equal to R.id.button_show_toast?
    Log.d("v.getId()", i + "");
    Log.d("R.id.button_show_toast", R.id.button_show_toast + "");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "I am come from fragment.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However the issue is still remain. The Toast massage can show correctly. I think the issue is related to the v.getId().. Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not sure but *your project may contain two or more views having same ids* - `R.id.button_show_toast`. Try to search in your whole project.

Moreover you can define `@OnClick` method using `ButterKnife` as follow:-

```
@OnClick(R.id.button_show_toast) 
public void onShowToastClicked() {
   // Do your stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the funtion as:

```
@OnClick(R.id.button_show_toast) 
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
}
```